# ho-import 1: Import products using their categoryId instead of path?

Tags: magento-1.9, import, avs-fastsimpleimport

Currently Im using [ho-nl/magento1-Ho_Import](https://github.com/ho-nl/magento1-Ho_Import) to import product information in Magento 1.9.2.

1. I tried importing products using category path (eg:
   Computers/Keyboards) with success.
2. Is there a way to import products
   in magento 1.9 using their category ID (eg: _category=1405)?.

I cannot find the answer in their github site or issues area. Any help appreciated.

EDITED----------------------------------------------------------
additional info. an example of a file that worked ok with category path:

```
_store,ho_import_profile,sku,_attribute_set,_type,store,_category,is_anchor,_product_websites,cost,price,location,country_of_manufacture,name,short_description,description,manufacturer,qty,weight,status,is_in_stock,tax_class_id,visibility,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,image,image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,gallery,media_gallery

electronics,141565030710,Default,simple,admin,"Electronics/AV Accessories & Cables/Surge Protection & Filtration",Yes,base,98.94,98.94,"White Plains, New York",US,"Panamax M8-AV-PRO 8 Outlet Power Line Conditioner and Surge protector","Shop By Manufacturer Other Add my Store to your Favorites and receive my email newsletters about new items and special promotions! Panamax M8-AV-PRO …","Shop By Manufacturer Other Add my Store to your Favorites and receive my email newsletters about new items and special promotions! Panamax M8-AV-PRO 8 Outlet Power Line Conditioner and Surge protector --> Description Payment Information Shipping Information Terms & Conditions Item Condition: NEW Warranty: 1 year Brand: Panamax Features: total of 8 protected AC power outlets in two isolated banksi…",###EMPTY###,1,1,1,1,2,4,88,###EMPTY###,,/141565030710.jpg,"Panamax M8-AV-PRO 8 Outlet Power Line Conditioner and Surge protector",/141565030710.jpg,"Panamax M8-AV-PRO 8 Outlet Power Line Conditioner and Surge protector",/141565030710.jpg,"Panamax M8-AV-PRO 8 Outlet Power Line Conditioner and Surge protector",,
```

ANSWER-------------------------------------------------------------------

using         `'_category' => array(1, 3),` if you want to assign products to multiple categories or

`'_category' => '3'`, for single category must work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to just enter the ID and see what happens? I don't know Ho_Import well enough, but I know the underlying AvS_FastSimpleImport well, and in that it's possible. So I'd say it should work.

Comment: in my experience ho_import worked with complete path but I didn't make it using the id only. I will check documentation again. thank you for your excellent Avs_FastSimpleImport open source solution!.

Comment: avs_fastsimpleimport displays the following example for category product relationship. using _category with ID will work? $data[] = array(
    '_root' => 'Default Category',
    '_category' => 'Test2/Test3',
    '_sku' => '0815',
    'position' => 1
);

Comment: Yes, it's supported. I agree it's not well documented. We have it in the test sample, see https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/blob/master/test.php#L45.

Comment: Thank you. So we have to create a tree traversal hierarchy to pass that data in an array eg: '_category' => array(1, 3), on the other hand, using only the product category eg: _category => '3' directly will not work?, probably that is the reason ive failed

Comment: `array(1, 3) ` means that two categories with the IDs 1 and 3 are assigned, it's not a tree structure. If you just want one category, just the number (`3`) should be enough.

Comment: wauu.. ok i will test everything again. thank you!